# how to update parent object variable when child object variable is modified and same for it's parent and till most parent in nested JSON

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a situation where there is nested JSON till **N** children. I have rendered this **nested JSON** using **recursion** through the ng-template and provided a checkbox at each level parent to child.

When I update the variable for the leaf item then I want to update the variable of its parent and again to its parent and so on till I reach the outermost parent item.

Is there any way to call a function when the object variable is updated so I can modify the parent of it and the same for their parent as well or any other solution?

I need to update the checkbox status **checked** or **indeterminate** of the parent item based on the selection of child items and their child.

Nested JSON:

```
    {
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f0000",
      "name": "Parent A",
      "checked": false,
      "indeterminate": false,
      "childrens": [
        {
          "name": "Child A-A",
          "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f7277",
          "checked": false,
          "indeterminate": false,
          "childrens": [
            {
              "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f728a",
              "name": "Child A-A-A",
              "checked": false,
              "indeterminate": false,
              "childrens": [
                {
                  "_id": "60701c4257d02229840f72f5",
                  "name": "Child A-A-A-A",
                  "checked": false,
                  "indeterminate": false,
                  "childrens": [
                    {
                      "_id": "60701c4c57d02229840f735f",
                      "name": "Child A-A-A-A-A",
                      "checked": false,
                      "indeterminate": false
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Child A-B",
          "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f727e",
          "checked": false,
          "indeterminate": false,
          "childrens": [
            {
              "_id": "60701c3657d02229840f72be",
              "name": "Child A-B-A",
              "checked": false,
              "indeterminate": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f1111",
      "name": "Parent B",
      "checked": false,
      "indeterminate": false,
      "childrens": [
        {
          "name": "Child B-A",
          "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f7277",
          "checked": false,
          "indeterminate": false,
          "childrens": [
            {
              "_id": "60701c3557d02229840f728a",
              "name": "Child B-A-A",
              "checked": false,
              "indeterminate": false,
              "childrens": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "60701c4257d02229840f72f5",
          "name": "Child B-B",
          "checked": false,
          "indeterminate": false,
          "childrens": [
            {
              "_id": "60701c4c57d02229840f735f",
              "name": "Child B-B-A",
              "checked": false,
              "indeterminate": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO!

Your questions is broad and I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for. Is this maybe it?

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { items: [{ _id: '60701c3557d02229840f0000', name: 'Parent A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ name: 'Child A-A', _id: '60701c3557d02229840f7277', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ _id: '60701c3557d02229840f728a', name: 'Child A-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ _id: '60701c4257d02229840f72f5', name: 'Child A-A-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ _id: '60701c4c57d02229840f735f', name: 'Child A-A-A-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false }] }] }] }, { name: 'Child A-B', _id: '60701c3557d02229840f727e', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ _id: '60701c3657d02229840f72be', name: 'Child A-B-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false }] }] }, { _id: '60701c3557d02229840f1111', name: 'Parent B', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ name: 'Child B-A', _id: '60701c3557d02229840f7277', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ _id: '60701c3557d02229840f728a', name: 'Child B-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [] }] }, { _id: '60701c4257d02229840f72f5', name: 'Child B-B', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [{ _id: '60701c4c57d02229840f735f', name: 'Child B-B-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false }] }] }] };

const toggleCheckbox = objectScan(['items.**(^childrens$)._id'], {
  abort: true,
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'parents',
  filterFn: ({ value, context }) => value === context,
  afterFn: (state) => {
    const parents = state.result.filter((p) => 'checked' in p);
    parents.forEach((p) => {
      p.checked = !p.checked;
    });
    state.result = parents.length;
  }
});

console.log(toggleCheckbox(data, '60701c3557d02229840f728a'));
// => 3

console.log(data);
// => { items: [ { _id: '60701c3557d02229840f0000', name: 'Parent A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { name: 'Child A-A', _id: '60701c3557d02229840f7277', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { _id: '60701c3557d02229840f728a', name: 'Child A-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { _id: '60701c4257d02229840f72f5', name: 'Child A-A-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { _id: '60701c4c57d02229840f735f', name: 'Child A-A-A-A-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false } ] } ] } ] }, { name: 'Child A-B', _id: '60701c3557d02229840f727e', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { _id: '60701c3657d02229840f72be', name: 'Child A-B-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false } ] } ] }, { _id: '60701c3557d02229840f1111', name: 'Parent B', checked: true, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { name: 'Child B-A', _id: '60701c3557d02229840f7277', checked: true, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { _id: '60701c3557d02229840f728a', name: 'Child B-A-A', checked: true, indeterminate: false, childrens: [] } ] }, { _id: '60701c4257d02229840f72f5', name: 'Child B-B', checked: false, indeterminate: false, childrens: [ { _id: '60701c4c57d02229840f735f', name: 'Child B-B-A', checked: false, indeterminate: false } ] } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)